# trying to make json and pass it as body in Rest call in Python

Tags: python

```
{ "contact_entry": [
                    {"luid":"1",
                    "first_name":"vuvrpm",
                    "last_name":"basjrkkjst",
                    "phone_numbers":["919000000000"],
                    "emails":["yahoo@bingo.com"]
                    }
                ]
```

}

trying to make json out of following and pass it as body in Rest call
    first_name is generated randomly and stored in strFirstName.

I tried this

```
jsonStr = jsonStr+ "{"+ '"luid"' +":" +'"1"' + "," +"first_name" + ":" + """'firstName"""' + "," + '"last_name"' + ":" + '"basjrkkjst"' + "," + '"phone_numbers"' + ":" + "[" + '"str(xx_msisdn)"' + "]," + '"emails"' + ":" + "[" + '"yahoo@bingo.com"' +"]}";
```

Output is:

```
{ "contact_entry": [{"luid":"1",first_name:kxggqo,"last_name":"basjrkkjst","phone_numbers":["str(xx_msisdn)"],"emails":["yahoo@bingo.com"]}
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: 1) This is not valid JSON. Test it at http://jsonlint.com/ 2) Python has the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module. Use it.

Comment: Hi Lutz, Added valid JSON..

Comment: OK. Now try building JSON from a dictionary using the  `json` module.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module.

```
import json

first_name = "vuvrpm"  # random value

entry = {
    "contact_entry": [{
        "luid":"1",
        "first_name": first_name
        "last_name":"basjrkkjst",
        "phone_numbers":["919000000000"],
        "emails":["yahoo@bingo.com"]
    }]
}

print json.dumps(entry)
```

Will print:

```
{"contact_entry": [{"first_name": "vuvrpm", "last_name": "basjrkkjst", "phone_numbers": ["919000000000"], "luid": "1", "emails": ["yahoo@bingo.com"]}]}
```

(prettified):

```
{
    "contact_entry": [{
        "first_name": "vuvrpm",
        "last_name": "basjrkkjst",
        "phone_numbers": ["919000000000"],
        "luid": "1",
        "emails": ["yahoo@bingo.com"]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why u want to make json-like string? all you have to do is to create python dict and thats all.

```
import requests
my_json = { "contact_entry": [ {"luid":"1", "first_name":"vuvrpm", "last_name":"basjrkkjst", "phone_numbers":["919000000000"], "emails":["yahoo@bingo.com"]}] }
r = requests.post(URL, json=my_json)
```

every entry can be defined like this:

```
entry = {}
entry["luid"] = "1"
entry["firtst_name"] = "vuvrpm"
...
entry["phone_numbers"] = ["919000000000"]
...
```

and the output is 100% valid "json" (in this case dict):

```
{"luid":"1", "first_name":"vuvrpm", "last_name":"basjrkkjst", "phone_numbers":["919000000000"], "emails":["yahoo@bingo.com"]}
```

Comment: I have a script running which will generate random firstName and phonenumber for each contact entry.

Comment: u can add entry to dict like this: my_json["contact_entry"].append(another_entry)